# In JavaScript, what is the point of defining a function with default parameters for some arguments before other arguments without default parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, coding-style

I was reading the Redux documentation and something really confused me. Many, if not all, of the example reducer functions in the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles/#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions) have this kind of signature:

```js
function visibilityFilter(state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What is the point of providing a default `state` when the `action` is required anyway?

In that particular code sample, calling `visibilityFilter` without providing an `action` argument will result in a `TypeError` at the switch statement.

But in order to provide an `action` parameter, the `state` parameter must also be provided, and so the default value is overridden and useless. As far as I know, there is simply no way in the JavaScript syntax to call that `visiblityFilter` function while providing only the `action` parameter.

Is that just some funky/bad coding style in the world of Redux? What am I missing?

Comment: The question has been answered already but to explain this in redux take a look here https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/ i think the store.dispatch provides the state (scroll to heading: 'React Redux tutorial: Redux store methods' and look at how the store.dispatch method, which is being used to modify the store, is called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's some pretty strange code, but there is one case where the default parameter could be used - if `undefined` is explicitly passed as the first parameter:

```js
function visibilityFilter(state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}

console.log(visibilityFilter(undefined, {}));
```

(not that I would recommend writing code that looks like this in most cases)

With Redux in particular, this sort of thing can arise "naturally" because the function is a reducer, used with [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore/). If `createStore` is passed an initial state, it'll be passed along to the reducer as the reducer's first argument; otherwise, Redux's internals will explicitly call it with an `undefined` first argument.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that passing `undefined` would make JavaScript use the default parameter. So that I guess it does have some use, albeit quite funky. But then there is no way to override the default parameter as undefined, is there?

Comment: @Kal - If I understand what you're asking in that comment correctly, `undefined` is the default default parameter value. :-) If you have `function foo(a) { console.log(a); }`, `foo()` will output `undefined`.

Comment: @Kal no, there isn't. But if you're specifying a default parameter it's usually to avoid `undefined` and instead use something sensible for the function - e.g., a string or a number or whatever is contextually appropriate.

Comment: @VLAZ - You can actually do `function foo(a = undefined) { }`. And there's even a reason to, though not a particularly good one: It changes the arity of the function. `function foo(a) { }` has an arity (`.length`) of `1`. `function foo(a = undefined) { }` has an arity of `0`.

Comment: @Kal - As a final note, some folks (who don't use Underscore/Lodash) do `const _ = undefined;` and then use `_` in situations like CertainPerformance's example above: `console.log(visibilityFilter(_, {}));` At some point you might even be able to do `console.log(visibilityFilter(, {}));` as you can with array literals (at present, it's a syntax error)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wow, I learned something new. I can't think of a reason right now why you'd want to have a parameter but no arity. I suppose it comes up, if it is integrated into ES.